# Cypress. Saving text element to use for assertion

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

Im having issues with saving an element as text, to use later for an assertion.

```
cy.getR6('contact-lastName').clear().type('TestarNameChange').then((nameCheck) => {

  cy.getR6('contact-lastName').invoke('text').as('nameCheck');

  cy.get('.r6modal-buttons-right > .r6btn').click();

  cy.get('.r6loader').should('not.be.visible');

  cy.get('[r6-personal-details=""] > :nth-child(1) > .r6widget > .r6widget-content').contains(this.nameCheck);
})
```

The response i get from Cypress  is:
"cy.contains() can only accept a string, number or regular expression."

I have also tried the $div way:

```
cy.getR6('contact-lastName').then(($div) => {
    var nameCheck = $div.text()

    cy.get('.r6modal-buttons-right > .r6btn').click();
    
    cy.get('[r6-personal-details=""] > :nth-child(1) > .r6widget > .r6widget- content').contains(this.nameCheck);
```

Also tried to wrap it, with similar success.
})

Comment: What is the output when you `console.log` the `namecheck` variable in each scenario?

Comment: Note the last test `cy.get('[r6-personal-details=""]...` is within scope of `.then((nameCheck) =>...` so you can change `.contains(this.nameCheck)` to `.contains(nameCheck)`.

Comment: In the second block, you don't create an alias so `this.namecheck` will definitely not exist, but `nameCheck` will.

Answer (score 2):

There are few mistakes that you have done in both of your trials. To explain it I'll break your code into 4 parts ( block 1 )

```
//Step 1
cy.getR6('contact-lastName').clear().type('TestarNameChange').then((nameCheck) => {

//Step 2
  cy.getR6('contact-lastName').invoke('text').as('nameCheck');

//Step 3
  cy.get('.r6modal-buttons-right > .r6btn').click();
  cy.get('.r6loader').should('not.be.visible');

//Step 4
  cy.get('[r6-personal-details=""] > :nth-child(1) > .r6widget > .r6widget-content').contains(this.nameCheck);
})
```

Step 1 - You try to type the values in the nameCheck input box and you refer the input box element with **nameCheck**  inside `.then` ( There is no error in this step )

Step 2 - You try to get the typed last name value and assign it to Alias.

**Mistakes**

- You can get the text values of an element using `invoke('text')` if the value you want is a button name, paragraph text, etc. Ex: (`<button>Name</button>` will return "Name" with `invoke('text')`) But here I believe you need the value of the input box. In that case, you need to use `invoke('attr','value')`. (Here you don't even have to do it, will add the improved code bellow)

Step 3 -  You click a button and wait till the loader is not displayed. This step also have no errors.

Step 4 - You are trying to validate the existence of the value using the previously created alias

**Mistake**

- This is one of the common mistakes that cypress developers do. You need to understand the asynchronous nature of cypress. In your code, in execution from step 2 to step 4, all will be executed asynchronously. Which means when you use `this.nameCheck`, `nameCheck` is not defined. So you need to wait until aliases are created before using them (you can use `.then` to achieve it)

I'm adding the fixed code below. I have done a few modifications too.

```
    //type the last name and refer the lastname object with the name "lastName"
    cy.getR6('contact-lastName').clear().type('TestarNameChange').then((lastName) => {

        //extract the value of lastname object with .val() and wrap it with cy.wrap
        // assign the wrapped value to aliase named "nameCheck"
        //You can use  cy.getR6('contact-lastName').invoke('attr','value').as('nameCheck');insted of the below code too
        cy.wrap(lastName.val()).as('nameCheck').then(() =>{

        //As you can see, since we used .then, the next steps will be executed after the aliase is created
        cy.get('.r6modal-buttons-right > .r6btn').click();
        cy.get('.r6loader').should('not.be.visible');
        cy.get('[r6-personal-details=""] > :nth-child(1) > .r6widget > .r6widget-content').contains(this.nameCheck);
        })
      })
```

In your second code, one of the mistakes that you have done is using `this.` to refer the defined variable.

And the other mistake is using `.text()` to extract the value of input field (`var nameCheck = $div.text()`). You should use `.val()`

So if we do the same steps of block 1, according to your second try, it will look like.

```
        cy.getR6('contact-lastName').clear().type('TestarNameChange').then(($div) => {
            var nameCheck = $div.val()
            cy.get('.r6modal-buttons-right > .r6btn').click();
            cy.get('.r6loader').should('not.be.visible');
            cy.get('[r6-personal-details=""] > :nth-child(1) > .r6widget > .r6widget-content').contains(nameCheck);
        })
```

By any chance, if you want to use `cy.getR6('contact-lastName').invoke('attr','value').as('nameCheck')`, you can change my first samle like this,

```
    //Type text
    cy.getR6('contact-lastName').clear().type('TestarNameChange');
    //create alias and continue
    cy.getR6('contact-lastName').invoke('attr','value').as('nameCheck').then(() =>{
    cy.get('.r6modal-buttons-right > .r6btn').click();
    cy.get('.r6loader').should('not.be.visible');
    cy.get('[r6-personal-details=""] > :nth-child(1) > .r6widget > .r6widget-content').contains(this.nameCheck);
    })
```

Comment: Thank  you very much. Since it was a text element it seemed obvious to save it as such, but i understand now what the mistakes was. Your explanation is super clear and thurough.

Comment: Cool !! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to validate if some element contains text, use this:

```
cy.get('[r6-personal-details=""] > :nth-child(1) > .r6widget > .r6widget- content').should('contain', this.nameCheck);
```